# $model->save() does not save object params Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Just as background information, i'm relatively new with PHP and Laravel.
I started making a simple application to get some feelings with PHP and Laravel. In the application i want to create a object with some params and save this object in the database.

For this i created a migration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePlayersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer("var1")->default(0);
            $table->integer("var2")->default(0);
    }
    public function down()
    {
           Schema::dropIfExists('players');
    }
 }
```

I created a model (Player):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
use Log;

class Player extends Model
{
    private $var1;
    private $var2;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->var1 = $number;
        $this->var2 = $number;
    }
}
```

And a controller off course (PlayerController):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Player;

class PlayerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $player = new Player(20);
//      dd($player);
        $player->save();
    }
```

If i uncomment the dd($player) i get a json object in my browser what shows the player with `var1 = 20` and `var2 = 20` what is correct. If i check the player in the database, var1 and 2 are 0.

If i add `$player->var1 = 10;` above the `$player->save();` the value in the database is 10.

Why is the value of the vars, defined by generating the Player object not stored and it is if i change the var values after the object exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this part, you declare your own variable called `$var1` and `$var2`. I guess when you dump your object you, indeed, see your values.

```
class Player extends Model
{
    private $var1;
    private $var2;

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->var1 = $number;
        $this->var2 = $number;
    }
}
```

In Laravel, the values are stored in an array called `$attributes`.
When you call `$player->var1 = 10;` from the controller, the variable `$var1` is **private** and you wont have access to it.
Instead, php will call the `__set()` magic method and store your value in the array `$attributes`.
That's why it's working from the controller.

```
public function __set($key, $value)
{
    $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
}
```

To make it work, you can simply remove `$var1` and `$var2` declaration to force the class to use the magic method `__set()`:

```
class Player extends Model
{
    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->var1 = $number;
        $this->var2 = $number;
    }
}
```

[More about __set() in laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1385)
[More about setAttribute() in laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L517)

[Documentation about __set() in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set)

Comment: Just removing the var declaration is working like a charm. I also understand why its working with $model->var=x; now. One more question, i guess i dont need to declare the vars as they are "declared" in the migration? (I will also check your links later today) Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: `One more question, i guess i dont need to declare the vars as they are "declared" in the migration?`
Exactly. You mustn't declare them.